# Any given number will divide into some combination of 3 and 0's

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Now, I have to prove that any number could be made to divide into at least 1 arbitrary long sequence of 3's and 0's. That is, for any $n$ there always exist a number $x$ made up of 0's and 3's such that $ x\equiv 0 \pmod n$. The proof is supposed to be done by the pigeonhole principle but i can't seem to find it.

Any idea on how to solve it using any method?

Comment: Hint: first use pigeonhole principle to show that for any $n>0$ there is a number of the form $999...999000...000$ divisible by $n$.

Comment: How "made to be divisible"? As it stands your question does not give enough information to enable me to answer it. Do you mean that you can construct a number with $3$s and $0$s which is divisible by $n$?

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, if you can show that such a number exists then it is done.

Comment: Hint: Can you show that there exist two strings of threes of different lengths with the same remainder modulo $n$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, that is pretty straightforward. There are infinite number of combination's for the string of threes but there are only finite combination's for the remainder(0 - (n-1)). Still,how do you ensure that the remainder will reach 0. Am i missing something here?

Comment: When you have two colliding strings of 3s, subtract the shorter from the longer.

Answer (score 2):

If there are more pigeons than holes, then there has to be a hole that contains more than one pigeon.

Note that to reach your conclusion, it is enough to show that you can find $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_1\equiv x_2\mod{n}$ in such a way that $x=x_1-x_2$ is of the form you want. As Lahtonen said in comment, working with numbers made up of $3$'s will help you out.

So, what should you consider as pigeons or holes in order to reach $x_1\equiv x_2\mod{n}$?